# Is it possible to use aggregate on a queryset annotation?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-annotate

I am using [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) on a django queryset:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   my_m2m = models.ManytoManyField()

my_qs = MyModel.objects.all().annotate(total_m2m=Count('my_m2m'))
```

This yields the desired result. E.g:

```
>>> my_qs[0].total_m2m
>>> 3
```

How do I use [aggregate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/aggregation/) to count the total number of `my_m2m` in the queryset? E.g.

```
>>> my_qs.aggregate_m2m
>>> 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sum up, so:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Sum


MyModel.objects.annotate(total_m2m=Count('my_m2m')).aggregate(
    total=Sum('total_m2m')
)
```

but here it makes more sense to aggregate immediately:

```
from django.db.models import Count


MyModel.objects.aggregate(
    total=Count('my_m2m')
)
```